# Creating a custom analyzer with Nest (for email address)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a class with a `UserID` field which contains a mail address, and I would like to be able to search on that field either for an exact match, or for parts of the mail address with some exclusions.

For example, if `UserID` contains "john.doe@foo.com", I would like to be able to search for "john.doe@foo.com", "john" and "doe", but "foo" and "com" should be excluded from the indexing.

I've tried to create a custom analyzer which uses a stop filter with a list of excluded words, and then apply a multi index to the property as in this example:

```
using Nest;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ElasticType]
public class ElasticUser {
    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
}

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        const string IndexName = "test_index";

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri: new Uri("http://localhost:9200/"), defaultIndex: IndexName);
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        // delete the index for the test
        var deleteIndexResp = client.DeleteIndex(IndexName);

        // create the custom filter and analyzer
        var user_id_stop_filter = new StopTokenFilter {
            Stopwords = new[] { "foo", "bar", "com" }
        };
        var user_id_analyzer = new CustomAnalyzer {
            Filter = new List<string> {
                "user_id_stop_filter"
            },
            Tokenizer = "letter"
        };

        // create the index with the custom filter and analyzer
        var createIndexResp = client.CreateIndex(IndexName, index => index
            .Analysis(analysis => analysis
                .TokenFilters(t => t
                    .Add("user_id_stop_filter", user_id_stop_filter))
                .Analyzers(a => a
                    .Add("user_id_analyzer", user_id_analyzer))));

        // add a mapping for the "ElasticUser" type
        var putMapResp = client.Map<ElasticUser>(
            m => m.MapFromAttributes()
            .Properties(properties => properties
                .MultiField(multi => multi
                    .Name(p => p.UserID)
                    .Fields(fields => fields
                        .String(s => s
                            .Name(p => p.UserID)
                            .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)
                        )
                        .String(s => s
                            .Name(p => p.UserID.Suffix("searchable"))
                            .Analyzer("user_id_analyzer")
                        )
                    )
                )
            ));

        // add a couple of entries
        client.Index(new ElasticUser {
            UserID = "some.one@foo.com"
        });
        client.Index(new ElasticUser {
            UserID = "another.one@bar.com"
        });
    }

}
```

However, this does not seem to work, as I can only search for exact matches, but email addresses are not tokenized splitting on non-words.

How can I get this multi-index to work as described?

When I try to run this query, I'm not getting any results:

```
GET /test_index/elasticuser/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "one"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using and what version of NEST/Elasticsearch.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to simply use the [`simple` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) on your `searchable` field:

```
...
.String(s => s
    .Name(p => p.UserID.Suffix("searchable"))
    .Analyzer("simple")                        <---- change this
)
...
```

The email will be tokenized on any non-letter characters and you'll be able to search for `john` and `doe`.

**UPDATE**

If you want to keep your list of exclusion, you can definitely do so. You can keep your existing analyzer, but instead you need to use a [`lowercase` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenizer.html) (i.e. the same as used in by `simple` analyzer) instead of the `letter` one.

```
    var user_id_analyzer = new CustomAnalyzer {
        Filter = new List<string> {
            "user_id_stop_filter"
        },
        Tokenizer = "lowercase"            <--- change this
    };
```

**UPDATE 2**

In pure JSON, here is what I have

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/users -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "email_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "lowercase",
          "filter": [
            "my_stop"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": [
            "foo",
            "bar",
            "com"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "parts": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "email_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then when I analyze `some.one@foo.com`, here is what I get

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/users/_analyze?field=email.parts&pretty' -d 'some.one@foo.com'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "some",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "one",
    "start_offset" : 5,
    "end_offset" : 8,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Can I also add a list of words to exclude to the analyzer? It was probably not clear from my original question, but I would need to have some excluded words.

Comment: With the "lowercase" tokenizer, if I search for "one" I get no results. I find something only if I insert a record like "some one@foo.bar". It looks like it's not tokenizing on the dot.

Comment: And also, if I insert "some one@foo bar", searching for the excluded words returns results anyway...

Comment: See my second update, I've provided a full recreation.

Comment: Then maybe I'm using the wrong query? I added the query to my question for formatting...

Comment: Your query needs to query the searchable email field (i.e. `email.parts` in my example). The following query will get you one result: `{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"email.parts:one"}}}`. Another thing you can do is specify `include_in_all: true` in your searchable field, then your query will work, also.

Comment: Thanks, the query that specified the "searchable" field works, but if I add "include_in_all" to the searchable field it's just ignored, it does not even appear in the mapping.

Comment: My bad, that second idea wasn't good actually, as [it does not make sense](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/include-in-all.html) (see the last paragraph). Anyway, you should be able to go forward with the first solution.

Comment: I see... well, now I have a way to get the results I want anyway, thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: Awesome, always glad to help!